# Android: Проблемы с программно создаваемыми виджетами

Tags: android, java

Цель - по нажатию на кнопку добавлять 3 текстовых поля, которые находятся в разных layout'ax. (1 поле во всю ширь экрана, 2 на одной линии с 3, 3 поле в два раза больше 1)

Вот наработка. На экране ничего не появляется.

```
setContentView(R.layout.create_buy);
    layoutik = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.for_main_text);
    layoutParams =
                    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(view == do_new_field)
            {

        if(last_field <= fields)
        {
            text[last_field] = new EditText(this);
            many[last_field] = new EditText(this);
            cost[last_field] = new EditText(this);

            text[last_field].setWidth(305);
            text[last_field].setHeight(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            text[last_field].setMaxLines(3);
            text[last_field].setHint("Название");

            many[last_field].setWidth(91);
            many[last_field].setHeight(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            many[last_field].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            many[last_field].setMaxLines(1);
           many[last_field].setHint("Сколько");

            cost[last_field].setWidth(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            cost[last_field].setHeight(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            cost[last_field].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            cost[last_field].setMaxLines(1);
            cost[last_field].setHint("Цена");

            text[last_field].setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            many[last_field].setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            cost[last_field].setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            layoutik.addView(text[last_field]);
            layoutik.addView(many[last_field]);
            layoutik.addView(cost[last_field]);

            last_field++;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно пойти другим путем, добавить их изначально в layout и сделать их невидимыми (android:visibility="invisible"), а после нажатия на кнопку изменить на видимые (View.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE));

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы пользователь смог создать до 50 таких виджетов.